# Can we achieve IND-CCA without a MAC?

Tags: block-cipher, mac, chosen-ciphertext-attack

In modern cryptography, IND-CPA is the lowest security we want. We want at least IND-CCAx security from encryption mode. Their relation can be found in

- 2007 [Authenticated Encryption: Relations among notions
  and analysis of the generic composition paradigm](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-44448-3_41), Mihir Bellare & Chanathip Namprempre

All classical block cipher modes of operations (CTR,CBC,OFB,CFB,PCBC), as stated [confidentiality only modes of operations in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Confidentiality_only_modes) can achieve at most Ind-CPA.

It is [easy to go beyond IND-CPA security](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44664/18298) with a secure MAC like HMAC, KMAC, etc., or even on can achieve Authentication Encryption mode where the provided security is more than Ind-CCAx.

Are there ways to achieve Ind-CCA without a MAC?

Comment: Could you consider this rather a canonical question?

Comment: If including a constant "check" value (such as that being done with NIST-SP-800-38F key-wrapping mode) is what @poncho mean with "CCA without MAC", then that's pretty boring.

Comment: I'm expecting more than though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a CCA-secure scheme that has no obvious appearance of a MAC. It's not an example of a general-purpose compiler from CPA to CCA security.

If you have a strong pseudorandom permutation $F$ with inputs/outputs of length $n + \lambda$ -- so either very short messages or a rather wide-block PRP -- then you can get a CCA-secure encryption scheme for $n$-bit messages:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \underline{\textsf{Enc}(k,m):} \\
    \quad r \gets \{0,1\}^\lambda \\
    \quad c := F(k, m \| r) \\
    \quad \mbox{return } c
\end{array}
$$

(decrypt by doing $F^{-1}$ and throwing away the last $\lambda$ bits.)

Comment: In addition, if you change it to $c := F(k, m||r||0^k)$ (and have the receiver check that the last $k$ bits are all zero after decryption, and fail if not), you also get integrity guarantees, again, without a MAC...

Comment: Ok, I've to admit that I was expecting something more complex.

Comment: @kelalaka That's just key-wrapping with randomized padding (without check value if we exclude poncho's idea).